# Mapping Two dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to map two dataframes in pandas , in DF1 I have

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXqEh.png)

my second dataframe looks like

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUsQM.png)

I want to merge the two dataframes and get something like this

[merged DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFErq.png)

on the basis of the 1 occuring in the DF1 , it should be replaced by the value after merging
so far i have tried

> mergedDF = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=companies)

Comment: What have you tried to far? Please include your code

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need `.idxmax()` method.

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Company')
merged['values'] = merged[[x for x in merged.columns if x != 'Company']].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: idxmax would work with an index , however company is a column and not an index , its givig syntax error

Comment: No, idxmax shows to which index the biggest value belongs to. With ```axis=1``` it shows to which column the biggest value belongs to. There was syntax error in my example, I've changed it and now it should work, sorry for that.

Comment: works however instead of compny name the index shows up